# Dictionary Cache with expiration time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, caching

I want to create a class to return a value. This value will be cached in a dictionary object for 2 minutes. During these 2 minutes I need to return the cached value, after those  minutes the dictionary cache object should read the value again. I need to use the Dictionary object not memorychache or something and I should execute the code in Test method class not a windows form or wpf.

I don't know how to make the dictionary object expired after 2 minutes in a test method.

```
public class CacheClass
{
   public string GetValue()
   {
      Dictionary<int, string> Cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
      string value1 = "Lina";
      string value2 = "Jack";

      return "cached value";
   }
}
```

Comment: I would create a new type (CacheItem<T> maybe?) and make the dictionary a `Dictionary<int, CacheItem<T>>`. The `CacheItem<T>` type would hold the `T` (whatever the value is) and a `DateTime` that keeps track of when the value was added to the cache. Then you can just check to see if the cached value is still valid before returning it or determine it needs to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Why not use a MemoryCache?  Microsoft has recently moved the MemoryCache into a namespace that does not have the baggage it used to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How can I create a Datetime to keep track of the cached value?

Comment: Maybe with DateTime.UtcNow?

Comment: @mageos it is mandatory to use the Dictionary not memorycach :(

Comment: How does GetValue() test anything?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public class Cache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, CacheItem<TValue>> _cache = new Dictionary<TKey, CacheItem<TValue>>();

    public void Store(TKey key, TValue value, TimeSpan expiresAfter)
    {
        _cache[key] = new CacheItem<TValue>(value, expiresAfter);
    }

    public TValue Get(TKey key)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key)) return default(TValue);
        var cached = _cache[key];
        if (DateTimeOffset.Now - cached.Created >= cached.ExpiresAfter)
        {
            _cache.Remove(key);
            return default(TValue);
        }
        return cached.Value;
    }
}

public class CacheItem<T>
{
    public CacheItem(T value, TimeSpan expiresAfter)
    {
        Value = value;
        ExpiresAfter = expiresAfter;
    }
    public T Value { get; }
    internal DateTimeOffset Created { get; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    internal TimeSpan ExpiresAfter { get; }
}

var cache = new Cache<int, string>();
cache.Store(1, "SomeString", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Comment: So the **test method** will run about 2 minutes only to wait for expiration? I would inject a `IDateTimeService` to the cache class

Comment: You don't want a unit test to run for two minutes. Ideally it's good to have some abstraction so that there's not a hard dependence on some `.Now` property. But in this case introducing that would drastically complicate the answer. And in real life I might just test this with a cache duration of <50ms and a `Thread.Sleep(200)`, something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the datetime when it was stored in the cache. This way you can test the item if it was expired. If the item isn't found or expired? call the resolvefunction for it.

Here's an example of a cache which can fill it self by calling a callback function:

```
public class MyCache<TKey, TValue>
{
    // type to store datetime and a value
    private struct CacheItem
    {
        public DateTime RetreivedTime;
        public TValue Value;
    }

    // the dictionary
    private Dictionary<TKey, CacheItem> _cache = new Dictionary<TKey, CacheItem>();

    private TimeSpan _timeout;
    private Func<TKey, TValue> _resolveFunc;

    public MyCache(TimeSpan timeout, Func<TKey, TValue> resolveFunc)
    {
        // store to fields
        _timeout = timeout;
        _resolveFunc = resolveFunc;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            CacheItem valueWithDateTime;

            // if nothing is found, you should resolve it by default
            var getNewValue = true;

            // lookup the key
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out valueWithDateTime))
                // test if the value RetreivedTime was expired?
                getNewValue = valueWithDateTime.RetreivedTime.Add(_timeout) > DateTime.UtcNow;

            // was it found? or expired?
            if (getNewValue)
            {
                valueWithDateTime = new CacheItem { RetreivedTime = DateTime.UtcNow, Value = _resolveFunc(key) };
                _cache[key] = valueWithDateTime;
            }

            // return the value
            return valueWithDateTime.Value;
        }
    }

    // the cleanup method, you should call it sometimes...
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // ToArray prevents modifying an iterated collection.
        foreach (var keyValue in _cache.ToArray())
            if (keyValue.Value.RetreivedTime.Add(_timeout) < currentDateTime)
                _cache.Remove(keyValue.Key);
    }
}
```

---

Example for caching textfiles:

```
class Program
{
    static string RetreiveFileContent(string filename)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(filename))
            return default(string);

        return File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var textFileCache = new MyCache<string, string>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), RetreiveFileContent);

        var content = textFileCache["helloworld.txt"];

        // sometimes you need to cleanup old data.
        textFileCache.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

You need to create some exception handling ofcourse....

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new cached item type that keeps track of the value along with the time the item was added to the cache:

```
class CacheItem<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public DateTime TimeAdded { get; }
    public bool IsValid => (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeAdded) < _timeToLive;

    private readonly TimeSpam _timeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

    public CacheItem(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        TimeAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Then change your cache collection to `Dictionary<int, CacheItem<string>>`

```
public string GetValue(int key)
{
    CacheItem<string> item;
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out item) && item.IsValid)
        return item.Value;
    return null; // Signifies no entry in cache or entry has expired.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want more simpler thing. According to your explanation, I couldn't figure out that why do you need a Dictionary or collection ? Because, your `CacheClass` just have a `GetValue` method and the an item isn't added from outside.

So, try something like that maybe it give you a start point;

```
public class CacheObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public CacheObject()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public static class CacheClass
{
    private static Dictionary<int,CacheObject> _cache = new Dictionary<int, CacheObject>();

    public static string GetValue()
    {
        if (_cache.Count == 0 || _cache[0].CreationDate.AddMinutes(2) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            var cache = new CacheObject
            {
                Value = GetValueFromSource()
            };
            _cache[0] = cache;
        }
        return _cache[0].Value;
    }

    public static string GetValueFromSource()
    {
        return "Jack";
    }
}
```

**Usage;**

```
var str = CacheClass.GetValue();
```